# Proactive Messaging: 'Authorization has been denied for this request' on server restart

Tags: botframework

We are using the botframework to power a chatbot experience in Microsoft Teams. Many of our use cases involve proactively messaging users, we have followed the documentation closely by storing/retrieving conversation references and trusting the serviceUrl from the retrieved reference, allowing us to successfully send proactive messages.

We have noticed that whenever we restart the bot, we get the following error when attempting to send a proactive message:
Authorization has been denied for this request.

We first encountered this error message after the bot had not been interacted with for at least a day which was resolved by altering the following statement with an increased expiration time on the `serviceUrl`:
`MicrosoftAppCredentials.trustServiceUrl(conversationReference.serviceUrl, new Date(8640000000000000));`

However, we now get this message every time the bot server is restarted, which happens often due to our CI/CD pipelines.

We can resolve this issue quite quickly by manually messaging the bot beforehand, which will then work, however this is quite cumbersome as we can have many deployments per day.

#### Steps to Reproduce

- Restart bot server
- Send a proactive message to the bot (we use a queue for this)
- Message will not send with the 'Authorization has been denied for this request.' error being thrown

**To Manually Resolve**

- Send a message the bot and wait for reply
- Attempt to send proactive message again
- Message will successfully be sent

### Additional context

Envrionment: Node.js Docker container deployed to AWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure this out by using the [botframework-connector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botframework-connector) to create the conversation and send the proactive message.

Assuming you have stored and retrieved a `conversationReference`, start by connecting to the bot

```
const msAppCredentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(MS_APP_ID, MS_APP_PASSWORD);
const client = new ConnectorClient(MSAppCredentials, { baseUri: conversationReference.serviceUrl });
```

Once connected, you can build up the conversation parameters and create the conversation:

```
const parameters = {
  bot: { id: MS_APP_ID, name: conversationReference.bot.name }, 
  members: [{ id: conversationReference.user.id, name: conversationReference.user.name }],
  activity: MessageFactory.text("oi oi oi"),
  tenantId: conversationReference.conversation.tenantId,
  isGroup: false,
  channelData: { ...conversationReference.conversation.channelData }
}

const resource = await client.conversations.createConversation(parameters);
```

Finally, send the message to the conversation

```
await client.conversations.sendToConversation(resource.id, parameters.activity);
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the `MessageFactory.text("...")` is imported from the `botbuilder` package and returns a `Partial<Activity>`

Answer (score 1):

You must trust the ServiceURLs once upon your bot restart. Generally the bot framework silently takes care of enabling the trust for each inbound conversation.   We keep an array of unique service URLs that we encountered from inbound conversations, and on restart of our bot we loop through this list and trust them all before initiating any conversations.

A similar issue is described here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2462

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ennova, do you know where I can find a list of the service URLs to trust?

Comment: Every incoming message from bot framework has the Service URLs to use. You will have to store them in db or file.   For example, if you see the schema for the JSON at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#full-inbound-schema-example,  one such "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/" .  To my knowledge, Microsoft has not published a full list and it can change (additionally when Skill bots are used this URL is not even a Microsoft URL, so you should just create a unique list of these URLs and trust at restart